# How to approve a contact in Empathy?

Tags: 11.10, empathy, contacts, msn

I have a tiny but important problem. Someone has added me to their contact list on MSN, this shows up with a notification. The problem is that I can't find out how to approve the invitation. How can I do it?

Comment: Same here. Was going to ask the same thing right now. In 11.04 at least I could logout, log back in and the option would appear. Now a notification appears and there is no way to accept/decline it.

Comment: This is still the case. I can not accept a contact from any email address (Not related for been a hotmail account, gmail account, etc..).

Comment: Changed this with Pidgin. Now everything is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Untick "Display incoming events in the notifications area" in Preferences. I had the same issue as you, as soon as I changed that option and logged out/in I was able to approve the request =) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/713066). Can you try restarting Empathy as suggested in the bug report to work around it?

Comment: In my case restarting Empathy did nothing. It just made the notification mention me again that there was X user that added me.